# Android Studio everything turns into .bin

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bin

I have a project that I havent opened for over 3 months. 
And then I just opened it. Everything turned red. Yes it is connected to Git, but I know there are unpush data there.

Everything turned .bin that includes (.java, .jpg)

I tried to look for local history but what remains there were few minutes data.

I dont know what happened to Android Studio, is it because of the upgrade ? 
My current version is 2.1.1

Is theres a fix to recover it ? 
Thanks.

PS.

My Git data might be not the latest data, since as I remember there are unpush data on this project.

Any idea, help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: I don't know what "Everything turned .bin" means? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: What happens when you re-clone the project?

Comment: all .java turned .java.bin so I cannot opened it. If I reclone it, ill lost some data there, i guess I forget to push it the last time I work on that project.

Comment: Show the output of `git status`

Comment: I don't think the Android Studio upgrade caused that problem because myself and many others have upgraded, and that hasn't been reported as happening and I know I have several Git projects in my IDE

Comment: heres the git status 
http://prnt.sc/c03r6a

Comment: the actual files are here http://prntscr.com/c03rml